# Required but not granted http access to 216.34.181.97 slows phpmyadmin down

Tags: phpmyadmin, httpconnection

I use a recently freshly installed phpmyadmin 4.0.5 for the administration of databases on a server with a rather restrictive firewall.

In the firewall logs I see that phpmyadmin tries to open an http connection to the address **216.34.181.97** - which belongs to sourceforge. Probably, this connection is required to look for and display update information.

Now what bothers me is the following:

When I block this connection by the firewall I experience that phpmyadmin does not react for around 1 minute when I directly after a login want to list up all tables of a database. After the "waiting time" everything runs as quickly as expected again.

When I allow for a http connection to 216.34.181.97 the initial slow down of phpmyadmin does not happen. This can be reproduced.

I saw some questions on some internet forums regarding a similar initial slow down of phpmyadmin - but these questions never were answered sufficiently.

So I post some questions here:

**Question 1:** 
Is the http connection only for looking for updates ??? Or is there more going on ??

**Question 2:** 
Can someone confirm the described behaviour of phpmyadmin?

**Question 3:** 
Should this inital automatic trial to get a connection to sourceforge not be handled differently by the phpmyadmin developers in future releases? At least it should not delay user interactions after the login ...

**Question 4:** 
Is there a parameter setting by which I can eliminate the trial to connect to sourceforge?

Comment: Although the IP is owned by SourceForge. PMA is probably trying to connect to phpmyadmin.net (hosted on the same IP). Just tested mine, it doesn't make the connection, very peculiar!

Comment: Meanwhile I found an answer to Question 4 by myself :
$cfg['VersionCheck'] = false;

See: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#VersionCheck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's just for version check
2. Confirmed
3. There is a parameter to bypass the version check: https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_VersionCheck

Also, the version check can be done via a proxy, see https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_VersionCheckProxyUrl and the parameters that follow.

Comment: Did not yet try the proxy solution. However, 
  $cfg['VersionCheck'] = false;
works and solves my problem. My general suggestion nevertheless is that someone of the phpmyadmin developers changes the way the version check is done - to avoid the delay of user activities after login. Could maybe done by Ajax ..

Comment: The verification is already supposed to be done asynchronously, see js/functions.js at line 3172.

Comment: Hm, strange. Had a (very) short look at the callback function for the JQuery $.getJSON (Ajax) call. Can't see why it should stop everything in case the connection is not build up. I use $.getJSON often myself in PHP/JS projects; it normally works. But this gives me an idea where and what to test if I find some time for it. So thank you for the hint about the position of the relevant javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `$cfg['VersionCheck'] = false;` to the "*config.inc.php*" file, doesn't seem to solve the problem.
You can always delete - or comment out - the code responsible directly in "*config.default.php*" file, but I wouldn't recommend it.
The best way I found to avoid the OP issue is to change the VERSION_CHECK_DEFAULT definition in the "*vendor_config.php*" file to false, `define('VERSION_CHECK_DEFAULT', false);` thus when the following code in "*config.default.php*" checks for it

```
if (defined('VERSION_CHECK_DEFAULT')) {
    $cfg['VersionCheck'] = VERSION_CHECK_DEFAULT;
 } else {
    $cfg['VersionCheck'] = true;
}
```

the 'VersionCheck' will be assign to 'false', skipping the connection to 216.34.181.97.
 I've tested it on Windows, but it should equally work on *nix systems.